Unable to use a component in another component of angular
I am not able to use a header component's selector tag in another component, but works fine in app.component.html alone
header.component.ts:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'cvy-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrl: './header.component.scss',
})
export class HeaderComponent {

}

app.module.ts:
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule, provideClientHydration } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


import { LoginComponent } from './pages/login/login.component';

import { ElectricalsComponent } from './pages/pages/electricals.component';
import { sharedComponent } from './pages/shared/components/shared.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...sharedComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    ElectricalsComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    provideClientHydration()
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }

shared.component.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { SideBarComponent } from './side-bar/side-bar.component';

export const sharedComponent:any[] = [
  HeaderComponent,
  SideBarComponent
] 

export * from './header/header.component';
export * from './side-bar/side-bar.component';

electricals.component.html
<cvy-header></cvy-header>

It is throwing
'cvy-header' is not a known element:

If 'cvy-header' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.

But in app.component.html,
<cvy-header></cvy-header>

It works,
I have tried all means but am not able to solve this and am getting
'cvy-header' is not a known element:

If 'cvy-header' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
If 'cvy-header' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.


When we use modules, a component can not use another component unless it's declared in the same module or the module where is declare import the module where the another component is declared and this last module export it. I try to explain (without succesfull) in this SO. Think a module how "something" that can be compiled by separate, so need know all the components in any way.

I suspect the order of the components in declarations.
Try to change the order of your declaration to make sure all components are available.
Before:
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...sharedComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    ElectricalsComponent,
  ]

After:
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    ElectricalsComponent, <——- 1
    ...sharedComponent, <——- 2
  ],

The Electricals component is injected before sharedComponent.

Tried, but issue still persists

@Yasik raam Ensure that ElectricalsComponent is part of AppModule or else any other module, If it is not part of the AppModule you have to export HeaderComponent from AppModule and import it into the feature module.
